# deserialization of Facebookapi.jsonobject in c#

Tags: asp.net, json, c#-4.0

I am trying to deseralize a Facebook.facebookapi.jsonobject. But the problem I am facing is as follows.

I have a jsonobject called **mefriends**. Now in the code below the parameter accepted are in string format only.I can't convert my jsonobject to .ToString() also. Everywhere I am getting the same codes.

```
Serialize mefr = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Serialize>();
```

How can i deserealize a json OBJECT?? I have a created a class with string variables and json object contains value in [name,id] pair.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use Json.Net to deserialize my JSON.  If you are using Visual Studio, add the extension for json.net.  Then the below code would be used to take a serialized json object and deserialize into a .Net object:

I will use a Book object in my example with two properties, Author, and BookName.

```
string json = "{\"author\": \"Brad Thor\", \"bookName\": \"Full Black\"}";

Book book = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Book>(json);
```

And so book.Author would give you "Brad Thor", and book.BookName would give you "Full Black."